# How to return a string

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I have a question, I have created a method `toString()`, I want this method to print out two strings a `int[]` and a `char`. While using `String.format()`, how would one go about this?

Comment: What does your `toString()` method look like now?

Comment: `String.format("%d%s", yourInt, yourChar);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way to print out the guys, includes

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.format("%s %c", java.util.Arrays.toString(intArray), myChar);
}
```

But who knows if this is the output you want? The devil's in the details of your desired output. Your question is **very** incomplete, very vague. Please consider giving us more of the important details of just what you're trying to achieve and how your current code does or doesn't work.

Comment: Yes that is the correct output, I didn't know the exact command of java.util.Arrays.toString(intArray).  I didn't want to be specific about this because so people will just say "Homework Helper."  with a question so simple.

Comment: @Galaga: you would have less criticism if you show your work, show your attempt, and then ask specific questions about your attempt. That way you're guaranteed not to get criticisms. I appreciate my answer being accepted, but it really was a SWAG, and still I'm not comfortable with the vagueness of the question. I'm not really sure just what I answered.

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is:

```
String.format("%s %s %s %c", string1, string2, Arrays.toString(array), character);
```

Be sure to import `java.util.Arrays` for this to work.